# Private constructor in matlab oop

Tags: matlab, oop

Matlab does not allow to define different methods to define multiple constructors with different list of parameters, for instance this will not work:

```
classdef MyClass

    methods
        function [this] = MyClass()
            % public constructor
            ...
        end        
    end    
    methods (Access = private)
        function [this] = MyClass(i)
            % private constructor
            ...
        end
    end

end
```

But, as illustrated in above example, it is sometimes useful to have **private** constructors with particular syntax that cannot be called from public interface.

How would you best handle this situation where you need to define both public and private constructors ?

Checking call stack ???

```
classdef MyClass
    methods
        function [this] = MyClass(i)
            if (nargin == 0)
                 % public constructor
                 ...
            else
                 % private constructor
                 checkCalledFromMyClass();
                 ...
            end
        end
    end
    methods(Static=true, Access=Private)
        function [] = checkCalledFromMyClass()
           ... here throw an error if the call stack does not contain reference to `MyClass` methods ...
        end
    end
end
```

Define a helper base class ???

```
% Helper class 
classdef MyClassBase
    methods (Access = ?MyClass)
       function MyClassBase(i)
       end
    end
end

% Real class
classdef MyClass < MyClassBase
    methods
       function [this] = MyClass()
           this = this@MyClassBase();
       end
    end
    methods (Static)
       function [obj] = BuildSpecial()
           obj = MyClassBase(42); %%% NB: Here returned object is not of the correct type :( ...
       end
    end
end
```

Other solution ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One sneaky trick that I've used to try and work around this limitation is to use another 'tag' class that can only be constructed by `MyClass`, and then use that to work out which constructor variant you need. Here's a simple sketch:

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        Info
    end
    methods
        function o = MyClass(varargin)
            if nargin == 2 && ...
                       isa(varargin{1}, 'MyTag') && ...
                       isnumeric(varargin{2}) && ...
                       isscalar(varargin{2})
                o.Info = sprintf('Private constructor tag: %d', varargin{2});
            else
                o.Info = sprintf('Public constructor with %d args.', nargin);
            end
        end
    end
    methods (Static)
        function o = build()
        % Call the 'private' constructor
            o = MyClass(MyTag(), 3);
        end
    end
end
```

And

```
classdef MyTag
    methods (Access = ?MyClass)
        function o = MyTag()
        end
    end
end
```

Note the `Access = ?MyClass` specifier which means that only `MyClass` can build instances of `MyTag`. There's more about using that sort of method attribute in the doc: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-attributes.html

Comment: Note that this is simply a refinement of @matlabgui's answer, but it uses language features rather than relying on the call stack.

Comment: Very nice ... In my example also thought of `(Access = ?MyClass)` in `MyClassBase` but could not see how to return correct type with `BuildSpecial()` ... great solution.

Comment: @Edric this seems like the right answer to the OP's question, but I'd be interested to know what sort of requirement might lead you to need a class that behaved like that. It sounds like you've previously had a need to do something similar - what was it, if you're able to say?

Comment: @SamRoberts In my case this was really to force users to use `ViewAs` method as indicated in comments to your answer ... though I agree this was not absolutely mandatory to hide `ob2 = MyClass(obj1, 'NewConventions')` constructor ... General idea is when you need to build a new object from internal state of another one without exposing this state, even temporarily, as parameters in a public constructor (+no need to deeply check these parameters as they already come from a valid object of the same type).

Comment: @SamRoberts mostly I've used this when writing a class which needs a documented public constructor (static build methods are *generally* frowned on for MathWorks-authored classes - but still we have a few such as `gpuArray.zeros`...), but for performance reasons or whatever, we need a constructor which can do things more efficiently / skip some error checking etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a constructor that accepts multiple syntaxes by taking advantage of `varargin`:

```
classdef MyClass

    methods (Access = public)
        function obj = MyClass(varargin)
            % Do whatever you want with varargin
        end        
    end 

end
```

You might, more typically, have some inputs that are required for all syntaxes, and then some optional inputs as well:

```
classdef MyClass

    methods (Access = public)
        function obj = MyClass(reqInput1, reqInput2, varargin)
            % Do whatever you want with varargin
        end        
    end 

end
```

If you want to have even more control over how things are constructed, I would have a constructor and then also have some public static methods that called the constructor.

For example, let's say I wanted to be able to construct an object either by supplying parameters directly, or by supplying the name of a config file containing parameters:

```
classdef MyClass

    methods (Access = public)
        function obj = MyClass(reqInput1, reqInput2, varargin)
            % Do whatever you want with varargin
        end        
    end 

    methods (Static, Access = public)
        function obj = fromFile(filename)
             myparams = readmyconfigfile(filename);
             obj = MyClass(myparams.reqInput1, myparams.reqInput2, ...);
        end
    end

end
```

Then you can create an object either with `o = MyClass(inputs)` or `o = MyClass.fromFile(filename)`.

If you wanted to allow people to construct *only* from a config file, you could then make the constructor private. And you could add additional public static methods if you wanted to call the constructor in other ways.

In any case, the main point is that the idiomatic way to have a constructor that accepts multiple syntaxes is to take advantage of `varargin`.

Comment: I agree with varargin and static construction methods, anyhow the idea here is more on allowing users to create object with classic constructor syntax while preventing them to call special construction syntax reserved for internal use only (for instance to create an object with particular state otherwise non accessible from public interface).

Comment: Imagine for instance a `ViewAs` method in `MyClass` that allows to create a light copy of some object in order to represent it in other conventions while still referencing initial object to avoid memory duplication and to allow manipulating the object in any convention (`obj2 = obj1.ViewAs('NewConventions');`). Obviously, `ViewAs` method will be something like `obj2 = MyClass(obj1, 'NewConventions')` but I would not like to expose this construction syntax in order to force users to go through `ViewAs` which is more expressive.

Comment: You can also imagine internal construction syntax that could lead to invalid states if not called from inside class methods.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking for - and if I understand correctly, then @Edric's answer seems to do what you need. If I'm honest though, I can't really imagine a circumstance in which I'd choose to create a class that behaved in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to go for a modification on your 1st option, but to modify the constructor to have an undocumented "mode" rather than just any input arg.

In the example below I gave that name `**private**` but you could have anything you want that the end users are unlikely to stumble across....

To be doubly sure you could still check the stack.

```
    function [this] = MyClass(i)
        if (nargin == 0)
             % public constructor
        else
             % private constructor
             if ischar ( i ) && strcmp ( i, '**private**' )
                 this.checkCalledFromMyClass();
             else
                 error ( 'MyClass:Consturctor', 'Error calling MyClass' );
             end
        end
    end
end
```